# Failed to connect to the host via ssh in Vagrant (Ansible)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ansible

Want to set up web-site locally, have Ubuntu 18.04 (Vargant 2.1, VM 5.2, Ansible)
Vagrant file contains ...

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  config.vm.define "web3" do |web3|
  end
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.56"

  # share/www
  config.vm.synced_folder "share/www", "/var/www", id: "vagrant-www",
    :create        => true,
    :owner         => "vagrant",
    :group         => "vagrant",
    :mount_options => ["dmode=775,fmode=775"]

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name   = "web3"
    vb.memory = 4096
    vb.cpus   = 2
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "90"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "0x3F8", "4" ]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "file", "console.log" ]
  end

  config.vbguest.auto_update = false

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     echo "ubuntu:ubuntu" | sudo chpasswd
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provision/playbook.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "provision/vagrant_ansible_inventory"
    ansible.sudo = true
    ansible.host_key_checking = false

    if ENV.has_key?('verbose')
      ansible.verbose = ENV['verbose']
    end

    ansible.extra_vars = { 
      ansible_ssh_user:   'ubuntu', 
      ansible_connection: 'ssh',
      ansible_ssh_args:   '-o ForwardAgent=yes'
    }

    ansible.raw_arguments = [
      "--private-key=.vagrant/machines/web3/virtualbox/private_key"
    ]

    if ENV.has_key?('tags')
      ansible.tags = ENV['tags'].split(',')
    end
  end
end
```

Run vagrant up (provision) and receive that error in console.

```
TASK [install python2] *********************************************************
fatal: [web3]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.56.56' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nalex@192.168.56.56: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/alex/Projects/vm/provision/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
web3                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

What I should write in vargant file to avoid this error?
It's necessary to use SSH, can I connect without it?

The same error on another machine (ubuntu 16.04) 
full stack

`<192.168.56.52> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<192.168.56.52> SSH: EXEC ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=/home/gil/vagrant/vm/.vagrant/machines/onno/virtualbox/private_key -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/home/gil/vagrant/vm/.vagrant/machines/onno/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ubuntu -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ControlPath=/home/gil/.ansible/cp/7ecc584fc8 -tt 192.168.56.52 'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ujsujrqhjylrxjabjmxzblqijoesfdib; sudo apt-get -y install python-simplejson'"'"''
<192.168.56.52> (255, '', "Warning: Permanently added '192.168.56.52' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\n")`

Comment: The same error on another machine (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: You should probably try this route: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my Vagrants for Ansible is the following:

```
       required_plugins = %w( vagrant-hostsupdater )
       machine.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant"

       machine.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        sudo su
        rm -f /etc/localtime && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
        echo 'Adding `sudo su` to the `.bashrc` for `vagrant` user...'
        echo 'sudo su' >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
        echo "Settings the hosts file and Ansible access..."
        bash /vagrant/scripts/hostsfile.sh
        bash /vagrant/scripts/ansible_ssh_key.sh
        echo "Done..."
      SHELL
```

Then the scripts:

hostsfile.sh:

```
cp /vagrant/files/hostsfile /etc/hosts
```

ansible_ssh_key.sh:

```
sudo su
USER="ansible"
HOME_DIR="/home/$USER"
useradd -m $USER
usermod -aG sudo $USER
passwd -d $USER
mkdir $HOME_DIR/.ssh
echo 'yourprivkeyhere' >  $HOME_DIR/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R $USER:root $HOME_DIR/.ssh
chmod 400  $HOME_DIR/.ssh/authorized_keys
sed -i 's/^#\s*\(%sudo\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*NOPASSWD:\s*ALL\)/\1/' /etc/sudoers
```

files/hostsfile

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

172.10.10.11 centos7-1.vagrant.local centos7-1
```

With this config you will be able to connect to your box

Of course, you should add something like this to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *.vagrant.local
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ansible.pem
    User ansible
```